# How to fix weird Python and urllib3 behavior with LMP USB-C gigabit ethernet adapter (connection aborted)?

Tags: network, python, ethernet

I have this adapter for my Macbook Pro from 2019.

[image]

I noticed something very strange that I'm debugging now since hours. I am using Ansible to create routes in Kubernetes and the following Ansible task works only if I am connected via Wifi but not when I am connect over the LMP adapter (I know, crazy, right?).

```
- name: "create route"
  k8s:
    api_version: v1
    kind: Route
    name: yolo
    namespace: "yolo"
    state: present
    resource_definition:
      spec:
        host: "yolo"
        path: ""
        to:
          kind: Service
          name: "yolo"
        tls:
          certificate:
            "{{ lookup('file', 'files/yolo.crt') }}"
          key:
            "{{ lookup('file', 'vaults/yolo.key') }}"
          caCertificate:
            "{{ lookup('file', 'files/yolo.pem') }}"
          insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
          termination: edge
    host: "yolo-master-server"
    api_key: "yolo-api-key"
```

With the LAN adapter I am getting the following exception from Python's `urllib3` module.

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
failed: [localhost] (item=one) => changed=false
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: one
  module_stderr: |-
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
        httplib_response = self._make_request(
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
        six.raise_from(e, None)
      File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
        httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
        response.begin()
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
        version, status, reason = self._read_status()
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 276, in _read_status
        raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 102, in <module>
      File "<stdin>", line 94, in _ansiballz_main
      File "<stdin>", line 40, in invoke_module
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 210, in run_module
        return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
        _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "/var/folders/zm/ld4b9y8n6ms5svr09mhly1sr0000gn/T/ansible_k8s_payload_7w51cfb3/ansible_k8s_payload.zip/ansible/modules/clustering/k8s/k8s.py", line 281, in <module>
      File "/var/folders/zm/ld4b9y8n6ms5svr09mhly1sr0000gn/T/ansible_k8s_payload_7w51cfb3/ansible_k8s_payload.zip/ansible/modules/clustering/k8s/k8s.py", line 277, in main
      File "/var/folders/zm/ld4b9y8n6ms5svr09mhly1sr0000gn/T/ansible_k8s_payload_7w51cfb3/ansible_k8s_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/k8s/raw.py", line 191, in execute_module
      File "/var/folders/zm/ld4b9y8n6ms5svr09mhly1sr0000gn/T/ansible_k8s_payload_7w51cfb3/ansible_k8s_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/k8s/raw.py", line 385, in perform_action
      File "/var/folders/zm/ld4b9y8n6ms5svr09mhly1sr0000gn/T/ansible_k8s_payload_7w51cfb3/ansible_k8s_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/k8s/raw.py", line 410, in patch_resource
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openshift/dynamic/client.py", line 132, in patch
        return self.request('patch', path, body=body, content_type=content_type, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openshift/dynamic/client.py", line 42, in inner
        resp = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openshift/dynamic/client.py", line 235, in request
        return self.client.call_api(
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 340, in call_api
        return self.__call_api(resource_path, method,
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 172, in __call_api
        response_data = self.request(
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 398, in request
        return self.rest_client.PATCH(url,
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 292, in PATCH
        return self.request("PATCH", url,
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 165, in request
        r = self.pool_manager.request(
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 78, in request
        return self.request_encode_body(
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
        return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 375, in urlopen
        response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
        retries = retries.increment(
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 531, in increment
        raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
        httplib_response = self._make_request(
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
        six.raise_from(e, None)
      File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
        httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
        response.begin()
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
        version, status, reason = self._read_status()
      File "/Users/tony/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 276, in _read_status
        raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
  module_stdout: ''
  msg: |-
    MODULE FAILURE
    See stdout/stderr for the exact error
  rc: 1
```

Does anyone have an idea what the reason for this could be and how to get the adapter to work correctly?

UPDATE:
There are apparently more people who have problems with their ethernet adapters after update to Big Sur. See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252026015.

Comment: Maybe your script is running on the wrong default for python?

Comment: @pemby: No, I already have hours of debugging it and it's the LMP adapter.

Comment: It's the adapter or it's the network the adapter is talking to?

Comment: @MarcWilson: It's literally the same network on both sides. I'm just switching between my intern WLAN adapter and the one from LMP.

Comment: Does the adapter as such work as it should, can you use it to connect to your LAN?

Comment: @nohillside: Well I have to admit that web pages were loading slower than normally and where lagging. After switching to using WLAN over the internal adapter the lagging went away. Strange thing is: I don't see any dropped packets or tx errors on my interfaces or something alike